# ChatBot Messenger with Dev Session like ChatFuel

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

This is what I'm Looking for :
I've created a Messenger ChatBot (for a restaurant) linked with Mysql datas.
I would like to build a secure platform with database (without Facebook login) and let restaurants owner writing their own restaurant's datas (menus, prices, ...) in it.
Once datas have been collected, I would like the user can test in Messenger their new ChatBot with all their datas.

So, I have some questions : 
- Is it possible to have an "empty" Messenger chatbot validated by Messenger in order to test restaurant's datas in it ? (Like Chatfuel in dev mode). 
- How can I do that ?
- Can I link with https://m.me/DemoBot?ref=1234 where 1234 is the Restaurant ID for exemple and display its datas ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by an "empty" chatbot, but you can point a Messenger app at any webhook. On the server side you can access any data you want from your DB.

Yes, you can pass whatever you want in the ref of a m.me link. On the server side you would then parse the ref and use it to determine what DB queries to make to show the correct data.